# Tracking clicks with Google Analytics on a link to AppStore

Tags: google-analytics

Tracking clicks with Google Analytics: 
I am trying to track clicks on a download button on my site (wordpress) that takes users to the AppStore.
I set up a goal and changed the button code to the following:

```
<a onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'AppStore', 'Click', 'top-button', '0');"href="
www.example.com">Download on the App Store</a>
```

and nothing is tracking. (By that, I mean that website visits are tracking but not clicks)

I have come across this support article (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en) that seems to imply that outbound links need an additional tracking code installed in the site's header, so i've added that in, and still no clicks are being tracked.
The support article also seems to mention that outbound links should be tracked as follows:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;">Check out example.com</a>
```

I am confused as to what code I should be using on the button to be able to effectively track clicks. 
Advice please!